# AngularJS: Pause $digest & watchers on hidden DOM elements

Tags: angularjs, optimization

We're building a single page application which has multiple pages loaded as tabs. Only the content of one tab is visible at any given time (much like a browser), so we want to temporarily pause `$digest` and watchers from executing on those DOM nodes of the hidden tabs, until the user switches to that tab.

Is there a way to achieve this, so that the model continues to be updated for the background tabs, but the view updates based on a condition.

The following code illustrates the problem:

```
<div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-show="tab.id == current_tab.id">
    <!-- tab content with bindings -->
</div>
```

The goal is optimization.

I'm already aware of [Scalyr directives](https://github.com/scalyr/angular), but I want a more specific solution without the extra features contained in Scalyr.

Comment: show some code, if we don't know how you hide elements, we won't be able to help

Comment: I think this means you have bad architechture - child models should contain only their own data, so you should not update model of hidden tabs, so you can just use ng-if.

Comment: `ng-if` removes elements from the DOM, so there are no watchers and no $digest.

Comment: @Rouby but it will also destroy the `$scope`, I need the `$scope` to be intact.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I am not sure that is the case, the child models do contain only their data. The problem with using `ng-if` is that it will not retain the state, when `ng-if`'s expression evaluates to `false` it removes the DOM node and also the model (`$scope`) linked to that DOM node.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some trial and error I've figured out the following directive which pauses all the children's `$$watchers` if the expression on the attribute evaluates to `true`, on `false` it restores any backed up `$$watchers`

```
app.directive('pauseChildrenWatchersIf', function(){
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch(attrs.pauseChildrenWatchersIf, function (newVal) {
                if (newVal === undefined) {
                    return;
                }
                if (newVal) {
                    toggleChildrenWatchers(element, true)
                } else {
                    toggleChildrenWatchers(element, false)
                }
            });
            function toggleChildrenWatchers(element, pause) {
                angular.forEach(element.children(), function (childElement) {
                    toggleAllWatchers(angular.element(childElement), pause);
                });
            }

            function toggleAllWatchers(element, pause) {
                var data = element.data();
                if (data.hasOwnProperty('$scope') && data.$scope.hasOwnProperty('$$watchers') && data.$scope.$$watchers) {
                    if (pause) {
                        data._bk_$$watchers = [];
                        $.each(data.$scope.$$watchers, function (i, watcher) {
                            data._bk_$$watchers.push($.extend(true, {}, watcher))
                        });

                        data.$scope.$$watchers = [];
                    } else {
                        if (data.hasOwnProperty('_bk_$$watchers')) {
                            $.each(data._bk_$$watchers, function (i, watcher) {
                                data.$scope.$$watchers.push($.extend(true, {}, watcher))
                            });
                        }
                    }

                }
                toggleChildrenWatchers(element, pause);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: @MatjažJurečič yes it does.

Comment: why do:  
                    <code> $.each(data.$scope.$$watchers, function (i, watcher) {
                            data._bk_$$watchers.push($.extend(true, {}, watcher))
                        });`
</code>
instead of just:  
data._bk_$$watchers = data.$scope.$$watchers;

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the reason I asked you to show some code was because of the reason @Rouby stated.

For performance purposes, you can use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show`. `ng-if` removes or restores the element from the DOM.

```
<div ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-if="tab.id == current_tab.id">
    <!-- tab content with bindings -->
</div>
```

`ng-show` is good to use when you want to style the hiding differently. For instance, you might want that a hidden element would only have its "body" hidden, with the header still appearing. It is possible with ng-show, you just have to define a CSS style for the class `ng-hide`.

If you want to keep the values of your $scope, you can bind those with a parent scope who would keep your variables intact.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not make this clear earlier, but there are some dynamically created child DOM nodes within the tabs which also need to remain intact (e.g.: Pop-ups within the tabs) and the properties of the DOM nodes (e.g.: Scroll position of a grid; multiple inputs that are partially filled). The business rule requires that the user do partial form completion, then switch to another tab and come back and complete filling the form. So basically, the tab needs to maintain state even when in Background.

Comment: So, as I said, you can store those values inside a parent controller. You can also store it inside a specific service. Services are singletons.

Comment: I'm thinking of writing a `ng-if` like directive which does not remove the DOM but instead caches it somewhere temporarily and then replace it back. But something better would be a way to leave the hidden DOMs intact and only pause watchers temporarily.

Comment: But the _tab content_ contains DOM nodes that cannot be reconstructed using the scope alone.

Comment: I don't see any better than your custom directive. :-(