# AngularJS: force refresh native one-time bindings

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to force a refresh on a one-time binding (native one-time binds present in v1.3+ not [BindOnce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce) library) **without having to recompile** the entire DOM node (which is what the [kcd-recompile directive](https://medium.com/@kentcdodds/angularjs-one-time-bindings-and-recompiling-templates-9857b2cead01) seems to be doing)

The following code illustrates my problem:

```
<span ng-bind="::firstname" refresh-on="firstNameUpdated"></span>
```

Here I want the content of `span` to be updated to the current value of `$scope.firstname`.

The way I imagine the way it would be done is by using the directive `refresh-on`, which forces a refresh when it receives the event `"firstNameUpdated"`.

Comment: Sure, that's the way of doing this. What keeps you from replacing `$watch` with `$on` and renaming it to 'refresh-on'?

Answer (score 12):

Shameless commercial here for something I've been tinkering on.

[angular-bind-notifier](https://github.com/kasperlewau/angular-bind-notifier)

Which for your use case would look like this:

```
<span bind-notifier="{fName:firstName}" ng-bind=":fName:firstName"></span>
```

Where `fName` is the eventKey, and `firstName` is the watched expression.

It works *sort of* like kcd-recompile (the core idea is the same), but with some main differences;

- I hook into the `$parse` service - so as to not recompile the entire DOM node.
- Support for multiple `key:val` expressions for rebinding.

---

With all of that said, I don't see a huge gain in doing this for a *single* boundValue.

It'd be a better idea *(imho)* to run a regular `{{}}` for a single value. You're just trading one `$watch` for the other here, kcd-recompile and bind-notifier only ever really shines brightly when you have multiple values to refresh occasionally.

Answer (score 10):

I had to do this because I was using angular-datatables and I didn't want the data-table to keep refreshing every time a carousel with a 5-second timer changed images on it. But, I also wanted to be able to refresh the table under specific circumstances.

What I did was wrap the entire datatable in an ng-if="data", and I set one-time-bindings to all the ng-repeats in the table (I had more than one. One to dynamically set columns, one for the rows).

Then, when I want to refresh the table, I do this first:

```
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.data = null;
    });
});
//Put code to set $scope.data to a new value here
```

This removes the entire table from the dom before it is re-created. When it is re-created, the one-time-bindings will re-bind. It's a little expensive, but it works.

So that's your answer. If you remove a section of html with a one-time-binding from the DOM with ng-if, and then put it back in, it will re-bind to a new value.

Comment: I was already aware of `ng-if` but it recompiles the DOM elements every time, expensive and results in slight delays. Which is not what I want (mentioned in the original question). Anyway, the underlying issue was to reduce the number of watchers by reducing the number of binds, I solved it another way which you can see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801907/angularjs-pause-digest-watchers-on-hidden-dom-elements

Comment: Yeah, it is definitely expensive, and not advised unless you use it infrequently. What you posted looks a lot better. I appreciate you posting it since I'm going to steal it and start using it immediately!

Comment: `$timeout` already calls a rootScope.$apply... https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/timeout.js#L64

Comment: You're right. I understood angular much more poorly than I thought when I wrote that.